# Does encryption add any benefit if I'm using SSL?

Tags: encryption, ssl

I recently stumbled across [this](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) article on securing Web API endpoints.

If I'm using SSL, is there any advantage to encrypting the user string in the header? What are the risks if I include the user key (Id) as plaintext instead of ciphertext?

Answer (score 1):

TLS is transport-level security. I.e. the data is not secured by TLS before the data reaches the transport and after that. If your data is long-term and/or you keep them elsewhere besides using during the transport session, then it might make some sense to keep them encrypted (and then transfer them encrypted if possible). If your data lifetime is short and the data makes sense only during the transport session, then there's no much sense in encrypting the data besides TLS.

Answer (score 1):

The author of the article is basically combining the concepts of a user identifier and a user secret into a single cryptographic token.  If you choose to send a user identifier in plaintext instead, then that user identifier must be kept secret (just as the token must be kept secret).  As long as that secrecy is maintained there is no advantage to using the token.

Note that this system doesn't seem very secure as presented.  If an attacker can guess a valid user identifier then they can generate a valid token.  The author is basically using RSA as a glorified hash function.  I'd recommend you look for another reference.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for other references?

Comment: I wouldn't try to invent anything.  If I were doing something simple, I'd just authenticate with [HTTP basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (only over HTTPS).  For something more complex I'd probably use [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/).  You can also see [how Amazon authenticates web services](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html), though this is overkill if you always use SSL/TLS.